# can't install ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS "Precise Pangolin" - Release i386

Tags: 12.04

[image: boot errors]

```
cp: can't stat '/custom-installation/initrd-override/*': No such file or directory unable to open '/dev/dm-0'
```

I am stuck and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Are you attempting to install ('Wubi' mode) )within Windows? What version of Windows?

Comment: Are you trying to dual boot?

Answer (score 2):

Probably your installation source is corrupt. Have you checksummed your ISO file?

Comment: And where did you get this install from? NOTE: the latest LTS version is **14.04.3**. Why are you attempting to install **12.04**?

Comment: @user2274418 -- ISO file checked by winMd5Sum and it coresponds to one on page so i think thats not a problem (btw i checked 14.04.3) the fact that i used 12.04 was that both of them weren't working and i downloaded it from ubuntu main page..

Comment: Nevermind guys.. i managed to somehow fix it.. the solution could be using another usb booting program.. But thx for ur help.